# Pass python list into json

Tags: python, json, django

I have a list in python (Django) that I'd like to pass as a json response. But when I console log the data out I get an empty array called num.

```
numbers = [10,15,20]
def get_data(request, *args,**kwargs):
data = {
    'num': numbers,
    
    
}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

In flask I would use jsonify:

```
from flask import jsonify
def get_data(request, *args,**kwargs):
    data = {
        'num': numbers,
    }
return jsonify(data)
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. They are using Django, not Flask, and the problem isn't related to the response function they use.